# rqt_plot does not display topic

Tags: rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running my simulation on ros noetic, rqt_plot cannot display any topics anymore because of the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rqt_plot/plot_widget.py", line 230, in on_subscribe_topic_button_clicked
    self.add_topic(str(self.topic_edit.text())) File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rqt_plot/plot_widget.py", line 290, in add_topic
    self._rosdata[topic_name] = ROSData(topic_name, self._start_time)  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rqt_plot/rosplot.py", line 108, in __init__
    self.field_evals = generate_field_evals(fields)   File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rqt_plot/rosplot.py", line 207, in generate_field_evals
    raise RosPlotException("cannot parse field reference [%s]: %s" % (fields, str(e))) rqt_plot.rosplot.RosPlotException: cannot parse field reference [['external_torques[0]']]: module 'string' has no attribute 'atoi' Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rqt_plot/rosplot.py", line 201, in generate_field_evals
    slot_num = string.atoi(rest[:rest.find(']')]) AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'atoi'
```

So it is mostly about the last line concerning rosplot.py. I have found the cause of this problem on this forum:
https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_plot/pull/57
Which seems to be a bug in rqt_plot.

And a solution on this forum:
https://answers.ros.org/question/362951/rqt_plot-noetic-does-not-display-arrays-fields/ Which is to replace string.atoi with int(). However, I cannot edit the file rosplot.py since it is read only and also, I read everywhere that you shouldn't just edit files in ros rqt. How can I fix this bug then? Or is there a way to edit this file safely?

---

Solution: updating from rqt_plot 0.4.12 to 0.4.13.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386988/rqt_plot-does-not-display-topic/) by [jessievd](https://answers.ros.org/users/83455/jessievd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2021-09-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-09-21**:
So you solved #q385758?

**Comment by [jessievd](https://answers.ros.org/users/83455/jessievd/) on 2021-09-21**:
sorry yes!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-09-21**:
Then please post an answer there to explain what you did to solve it.

**Comment by [jessievd](https://answers.ros.org/users/83455/jessievd/) on 2021-09-21**:
yes, done!

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-09-21**:
You have to write the answer and its explanation in below answer box.

**Comment by [jessievd](https://answers.ros.org/users/83455/jessievd/) on 2021-09-21**:
That is what I did right, I don't understand?

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-09-21**:
You are writing your answer in the question section.

**Comment by [jessievd](https://answers.ros.org/users/83455/jessievd/) on 2021-09-21**:
changed it

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-09-21**:
@jessievd Both of the links in your description are 13 months old. I find it hard to believe this bug is still in there after all that time. What version of `rqt_plot` are you using?

**Comment by [jessievd](https://answers.ros.org/users/83455/jessievd/) on 2021-09-22**:
@Mike Scheutzow When I use `apt list rqt_plot -a` it says;

```
 Listing... Error!
E: input:0-8: error: Expected pattern
   rqt_plot
   ^^^^^^^^
```

However, if I use `apt list python3 -a` (as you can see in the error message in my question, rqt_plot is within python3 directory) it says:

```
   python3/focal,now 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]

python3/focal 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 i386
```

I already did `sudo apt-get update python3` and `sudo apt-get upgrade python3`, but did not work.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-09-22**:
The `apt` package name would be `ros-noetic-rqt-plot`:

```
$ apt list ros-noetic-rqt-plot
Listing... Done
ros-noetic-rqt-plot/focal 0.4.13-1focal.20210727.072847 amd64
```

@Mike Scheutzow wrote:

> @jessievd Both of the links in your description are 13 months old. I find it hard to believe this bug is still in there after all that time. What version of `rqt_plot` are you using?

there is a chance it's actually old, seeing as @jessievd mentioned not using a regular install, but "a company installation of ROS" in #q385758.

**Comment by [jessievd](https://answers.ros.org/users/83455/jessievd/) on 2021-09-22**:
This is what I get.

```
ros-noetic-rqt-plot/focal,now 0.4.12-1focal.20201017.004142 amd64 [installed]
```

How do I get it to 0.4.13 as you have? Already ran `sudo apt-get upgrade ros-noetic-rqt-plot` but did not help

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-09-22**:
I would suggest to ask whoever manages that installation method you're using at the company you work.

It could be they're using the wiki/SnapshotRepository, in which case lagging behind is actually a *feature*.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-09-28**:
@jessievd: I realise you got some confusing input previously, but: if you solve your problem, and there is no answer which already describes the solution, post your solution as an answer and accept your own answer.

Do not edit your original post to add the solution. That has close to zero visibility.

In this case however, @Mike Scheutzow already posted the answer and he was right (as you confirmed with your edit).

So please accept @Mike Scheutzow's answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of his answer.

**Comment by [jessievd](https://answers.ros.org/users/83455/jessievd/) on 2021-09-28**:
Did it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both of the links in your description are 13 months old. You need to upgrade your `ros-noetic-rqt-plot` apt package to version 0.4.13.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2